# C# SerialPort Encoding conversion to byte[]

Tags: c#, encoding, serial-port

i know I recieve some data in byte format from the serial port (a u-blox GPS device), that should look like this:

```
Hex:        0xB5 0x62 0x01 0x21
ISO 8859-1: µ    b    1    !
```

So i read a string s from the command line and print in in a text box and it looks like:

```
Tbx:        ?    b       !
```

That seems fine, as the textbox isn't configured to respect the encoding.

When I try to convert the string s to the bytes (which should look like the first Hex-line), I get

```
Bytes(d):   63   98   1    33
Bytes(h):   0x3F 0x62 0x1  0x21
```

As you see, the µ char is wrong encoded, somewhere along my way.
Here is the code:

```
string s = port.ReadLine();
System.Text.Encoding iso_8859_1 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
System.Text.Encoding ascii = port.Encoding;

byte[] bASCII = ascii.GetBytes(s);
byte[] bICO = Encoding.Convert(ascii, iso_8859_1, bASCII);
```

Where do I mess up the µ?

Comment: Is it not possible to use the binary `Read(byte[],int,int)` method, and forget about encodings?

Comment: use unicode instead of iso-8859-1

Comment: @Marc Graell: Not really, because I get a lot of other messages in ASCII plaintext (NMEA) which I forward to some other device. So I would worry about encoding again, just on a different point.

(a)Jaster: Doesn't work neither.

Comment: @buhlara if you are *forwarding* them, that makes it *even more appropriate* to process them without encoding/decoding...

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
System.Text.Encoding iso_8859_1 = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
port.Encoding = iso_8859_1;

string s = port.ReadLine();

byte[] theBytes = iso_8859_1.GetBytes(s);
```

Comment: I ran into this exact problem and this is indeed the solution.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: A year after my original comment, I ran into this exact problem again with different hardware.  This answer is still indeed the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 0x3F character is actually a question mark.

Try *setting* the port.Encoding to Encoding.ASCII.  Set this value **before** calling port.ReadLine();

Otherwise you might have to read raw bytes and look for a \r or \n.

Comment: Tried setting the port to ASCII (although it already is ASCII), didn't change anything.